# How to compile C code with pcaplib to WASM

Tags: c, webassembly, libpcap

WasmFiddle
We have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pcap.h>

void packet_handler(unsigned char *user_data, const struct pcap_pkthdr *pkthdr, const unsigned char *packet) {
    printf("Packet captured!\n");
    // Process the packet data here
}

int main() {
    pcap_t *handle;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct pcap_pkthdr header;

    // Define the network interface to capture packets from
    char dev[] = "eth0";

    // Open the network interface for packet capture
    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

    // Start capturing packets
    pcap_loop(handle, 0, packet_handler, NULL);

    // Close the packet capture handle
    pcap_close(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Trying install Emscripten but it stuck ubuntu on installation
Get functions from pcaplib but without luck